# Soap/WSDL2OBJC Webservice for iPhone improving performance

Tags: iphone, web-services, wsdl

i'm using wsdl2objc to consume a WSDL and my biggest problem is that i sometimes get a response which has a size of 500 kb or bigger. This is unaccaptable for edge so i'm looking for ways to improve the performance. My first attempt was to use gzip but somehow it does not seem to work, if somebody used this successfully please point me in the right direction (i enabled the gzip on the webserver and edited the generated webservice code with adding  [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];). Does anybody had to deal with a similar problem and found a solution how to handle a big responses with wsdl2objc? Thanks in advance for your help.

kukudas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you clearly have access to the server : is it not possible to use a lighter response format such as JSON ?

Comment: i'm marking this as solution because no one else responded and it's probably a good way to go.